# PHP Mysql ASC AND DESC Order Proper use?

Tags: php, mysql

how can I use the ASC AND DESC in php with mysql ? here's my code below.

```
<?php
    $gallery_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `control_id` = '{$row['control_id']}'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($gallery_query) == 0){
 ?>
     <td align="center">
           <p>No Photos Available</p>
     </td>
 <?php
      } else{
         while($photo = mysql_fetch_assoc($gallery_query)){
 ?>
  <td align="center">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photo<?php echo $photo['id']?>">
            <div class="popover_img">
                 <img src="<?php echo $photo['photo']?>">
            </div>
        </a>
  </td>
```

and I want to do is Ascending the data from the latest photo to old photo

Comment: if you have an insertion date column (create_date/created_at something like that) in your table just use order by descending on your query.

Comment: oohh I see that's what  I want hahaha thanks bro!!

Comment: yeah I forgot I have inserted date in the table

Comment: yes just use that, if its datatype is `DATETIME/TIMESTAMP` an order by in your query should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then add `ORDER BY` to query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `control_id` = '{$row['control_id']}' ORDER BY date DESC");
```

use **date** (created date) column to order rather id or both

**ORDER BY DESC** :- means last to first(new to old) records

for more :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Better to use the date than the id

Comment: Kriz is correct better use date ^_^ to control what date the photo has been added

Comment: thanks added date to answer you can use id also or date as per your requirement i am giving only syntax for order

Comment: Actually, AUTO_INCREMENT counter can be modified that's why the date/timestamp the row was added is ideal.

Comment: glad it's helpful for you you can accept as an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can change your sql query in php like this

```
SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `control_id` = '{$row['control_id']} ORDER BY 'ColumnID' DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

And Yes I forgot I have Column in the table named `post_date` and here's the correct answer to my question

here's the code

```
         <table style="width:100%;padding:0px;">
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                            $gallery_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `control_id` = '{$row['control_id']}' ORDER by `post_date` DESC");
                            if(mysql_num_rows($gallery_query) == 0){
                        ?>
                            <td align="center">
                                <p>No Photos Available</p>
                            </td>
                        <?php
                            } else{
                            while($photo = mysql_fetch_assoc($gallery_query)){
                        ?>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photo<?php echo $photo['id']?>">
                                <div class="popover_img">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $photo['photo']?>">
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <?php 
                                }
                            } 
                        ?>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using DESC?  Descending would mean the larger timestamp to the smaller timestamp (that is the latest one to the oldest one)

Comment: You can verify the output :)

Answer (score 0):

its very simple

```html
SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE control_id = 'YOUR ID' ORDER BY YOUR PHOTO ID COLUMN DESC
```

1)if you want to display your latest photo to old photo than you have to use in query "DESC" i.e descending order for e.g "select * from gallery where control_id='2' order by my_photo_id DESC

2)and if you want to display old photo to latest photo than you can use in query "ASC" i.e Ascending order and by default data will be display in ascending order. for e.g "select * from gallery where control_id='2' order by my_photo_id ASC

For more information you can learn from this link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp